# single .js file sharing it's data with 2 html page calls

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have 2 html pages that use functions in a single .js file. The second page needs access to data first initialised by the first page when it calls the .js file:

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
{
var destinationTo = "";
var departingFrom = "";
var departing = "";
var returning = "";
var numAdults = "";
var numChildren = "";
var travelType = "";

$("#departing").datepicker();
$("#returning").datepicker();
$("#orderTickets").click(function() 
{
    destinationTo = $("#myDestination option:selected").text();
    departingFrom = $("#myDepart option:selected").text();

    departing = $("#departing").val();
    returning = $("#returning").val();

    numAdults = $("#adults option:selected").text();
    numChildren = $("#children option:selected").text();

    travelType = $("#class option:selected").text();
    var item = document.getElementById("hiddenListItem");
    if (departing === "" && returning === "")
    {
        alert("Please enter your travel dates.");
    }
    else if (item.style.display !== 'none' && returning === "")
    {
        alert("Please enter a return date.");

    }
    else if (departing === "") 
    {
        alert("Please enter a departing date.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (item.style.display !== 'list-item')
        {
            var isConfirmed = confirm("Please confirm your travel: outward journey from " + departingFrom + " on " + departing + " to " + destinationTo  + 
            " adults " + numAdults + " children " + numChildren + " travelling in " + travelType + " coach " + "?");
            if(isConfirmed == true)
            {
                window.location.href = 'PersonDetail.html';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var isConfirmed = confirm("Please confirm your travel: outward journey from " + departingFrom + " on " + departing + " to " + destinationTo + " returning on " + 
            returning + " adults " + numAdults + " children " + numChildren + " travelling in " + travelType + " coach " + "?");
            if(isConfirmed == true)
            {
                window.location.href = 'PersonDetail.html';
            }
        }
    }
});
$("#startAgain").click(function()
{
    document.getElementById("travelDetailsForm").reset();
});
$("#finish").click(function() 
{
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var addy1 = $("#address1").val();
    var addy2 = $("#address2").val();
    var addy3 = $("#address3").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var number = $("#number").val();

    travelType = $("#class option:selected").text();
    // test
    confirm("name " + name + " addy1 " + addy1 + " addy2 " + addy2 + " addy3 " + addy3 + " email " + email + " number " + number + " detion " + destinationTo);

});

});
```

I want to be able to access the data in the function call "#orderTickets" in the function "#finish" to dispay the order detils to the user etc. I thought I could put the variables in the global position, but think they reset themselves when another page accesses the .js file.

HTML and javascript are not my thing, would appreciate some help with this.

EDIT: the user clicks "order tickets" on html page 1, .js validates page 1 then directs to html page 2, (same .js file) validates page 2 and hopefully displays data collected from page 1 & 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partly correct when you say that the variables reset themselves. What actually happens is that each page has their own environment, so the variables from the previous page doesn't even exist any longer. Each page gets their own set of brand new variables.

Also, the variables that you have aren't even global in the page. They exist in the scope of the ready event handler. The reason that the variables exist at all after the ready event handler finishes is that they are caught in the closure of the click event handlers.

To keep the values from one page to the next, you have to store them outside of the page itself. You can for example put the values in a cookie, which you then can read in the second page.

Comment: Cookies, probably the best option.